# Polygon Mouse Left Button Down Not Firing and Polygon child possible or not?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a polygon which has a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event. When I click near its edges (say 10 pixes inside from the borders) the event is not called. What could be the problem of this?

Secondly, can we add child of a polygon?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Polygon p = new Polygon() { 
    Stroke = Brushes.Black, 
    StrokeThickness = 2, 
    Points = new PointCollection() {new Point(10,10), new Point(50,10), 
    new Point(56, 45) }};    
    p.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(p_MouseLeftButtonDown);
    mygrd.Children.Add(p); 
}

void p_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Entered"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you have?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question instead.

Comment: what do you mean "can we add child of a polygon"?

Comment: Something like

mypolygon.Children.Add(new Label());

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I do not know what you are doing, but you can create the polygon as a brush and apply this brush as a background control, in this control you can place such a label or text block. A polygon can not add any controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the polygon a fill brush and your mouse event fires

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Polygon p = new Polygon() {
    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Transparent, // or something else
    Points = new PointCollection() {new Point(10,10), new Point(50,10), new Point(56, 45) }};
  p.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(p_MouseLeftButtonDown);
  mygrd.Children.Add(p);
}
```